# Help identifying this newspaper font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

I am trying to find the fonts used in the following Logo for the Swiss newspaper "La Liberté". I've been trying to use whatthefont.com, but haven't had much success.

[image: La Liberté]

Comment: This is borderline spam at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell you right now that the subtitle's **Arial**.

By inverting the colors, removing the shadow/glow, replacing the background color with white, and straightening the letters; these were my results:

[image: WhatTheFont Search Results]

*(do a search for each fonts name to find the links)*

The closest two are:

1. **Country Western SC Fill**
2. **Beton EF Bold Condensed**

However, none of them are quite right completely. My guess is it's a derivative of some other typeface or custom job.

Comment: The link doesn't work: “Error Your search session has expired. Please start again.”

Comment: Ah, didn't realize WTF's searches had a session expiration... replaced link with screenshot

Comment: @alisamii, you might want to try typophile.com/typeid to see if you can get an answer there.

Answer (score -1):

I would have laid odds on the subtitle being Univers 55...

Comment: The **R** gives the lie to that. Univers R has a vertical right leg.